# how to += in Postgres 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

i am having a trouble to reassign a value, my teacher told me to use something like
var = var + (rest of the query)
but it aint working at all, here it is my code:

```
create or replace function recorrertablas()
returns void as
$BODY$
declare cursorx cursor for select id, nombre as nombres from tablas;
declare cursory refcursor;
declare rec record;
declare rec2 record;
declare consulta varchar;
--declare consulta2 varchar;
begin
    open cursorx;
            loop
                fetch cursorx into rec;
                exit when not found;
                consulta= 'create table ' || rec.nombres;
                --consulta2= '';
                open cursory for select * from atributos where idtabla = rec.id;
                loop
                    fetch cursory into rec2;
                    exit when not found;
                    consulta = consulta + '(' || rec2.id || ', ' || rec2.idtabla || ', ' || rec2.nombre || ', ' ||rec2.tipodedatos ;
                    if rec2.claveprimaria = 1 then
                        consulta= consulta +', constraint pk_ ' || rec.nombres || '( ' || rec.id || '));';
                    else
                        consulta = consulta +');';
                    end if;
                end loop;
            close cursory;
        end loop;
        execute consulta;
    close cursorx;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show your code. Is it PL/pgSQL block or plain SQL?

Comment: sorry, there it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to concatenate things use `||` operator or `concat()` function like below.

You've been using this operator, but for some reason you mixed it with `+`.

```
SELECT 'string' || 'part2';
```

or

```
SELECT concat('string', 'part2');
```

For your specific case:

```
consulta = consulta || '(' || rec2.id || ', ' || rec2.idtabla || ', ' || rec2.nombre || ', ' ||rec2.tipodedatos ;
if rec2.claveprimaria = 1 then
  consulta= consulta || ', constraint pk_ ' || rec.nombres || '( ' || rec.id || '));';
else
  consulta = consulta || ');';
```

When using `||` operator if any value evaluates to `NULL` the whole output will be `NULL`, but when using `concat()` function it will omit `NULL` values and still concatenate other arguments.